# Are global.asax, application_start, static variables, and unity container allowed to party?

Tags: asp.net, iis, static, unity-container

I am building up a Unity container in the Global Application_Start event and then stashing it away in a static variable which is then made globally available via a method on an interface implmented by the GLobal class and is then available, correctly cast on the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance , which works well for a time.  When the application pool recycles, the static variable is cleared out, The Application_Start event, is seemingly not reexecuted and the container doesnt have any of the registrations it started out with.

Has anyone else come across this issue? and were able to resolve it?

Comment: static variables are guaranteed to be thread safe apparently. So don't be telling me to be careful about static variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are using classic ASP.NET web forms. In that case I would advocate for using the `HttpApplicationState` (available via `HttpContext.Current.Application`) to store the container.

Have a look at the comments to Chris Tavares' answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880102/mvc3-unity-framework-with-multiple-configurations). Chris was the chief maintainer for Unity. He knows what he is talking about.

Comment: Yeah using classic web forms. A further investigation has elicited the fact that application_start is refiring, I am geting "SOME" registrations against my container, but I am looking at assemblies loaded in the current app domain to determine which ones have types I want to register, all assemblies are loaded on initial deployment but after a recylce only some are and I cant get from assembly B to assembly A (concrete implementations to service assembly) which is causing assembly discovery issue. I now preload assemblies if needs be, althoguh architecture could be tweaked.